# Reuse bowed floor joists?

Tags: joists

First, I'm just a homeowner who does a lot of building for myself.  No professional training. I got a used 12x12 raised platform that had a small playhouse on top.  Took it all apart and now am rebuilding it on my property.  The floor joist are pressure treated 2x10s.  If I orient the joists the same way as before, they bow down in the middle where the playhouse sat.  I would like to re-use them.

Couldn't I just flip them over, and then place the playhouse, wait for some settling to occur when the rain starts, then support them from underneath with a beam? That would turn a 12 ft span into 6 ft. I'm worried about the pressure treated wood having been stressed one way, and now having the forces on them reversed.... Are they still strong? The wood feels very bone dry and light, but I know for a fact that they are less than 6 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can flip the joists over and they’ll be just as strong. Most building specifications call for the joists to be installed “crown side up”. This allows the board to settle down over time when loaded (when furniture added, people traffic, etc.)

The amount of deflection (settlement) a board will have depends on species, grade, spacing, span, loading, type and amount of pressure treatment injected into the wood, etc.  However, rather than calculate all that, just install the joists crown side up.

Pressure treatment will reduce the joists strength about 10% - 20%, depending on factors listed above. A pressure treated 2x10 spanning 12’ at 12” oc will support about 150 lbs. per square foot (building codes require floors to be 40 psf) which is substantial.